# Using UINavigation with 2 toggleable views and a UISegmented control

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UISegmentedControl` and two `UICollectionViews`.

This `UISegmentedControl` makes it possible to switch between my two collection views.

Look at this image. To the left in the UISegmentedControl, you see a single item view display view button on the segmented control and to the right of that button is the grid display button.

Grid display button links to _collectionView
Single file display button links to _collectionView2

By default my app shows _collectionView first visited. Lets say I tap the refine button. My UINavigation takes me to another page then if I tap back button on that page it takes me back to the _collectionView page.

Now lets say I tap the single file display button to take me to _collectionView2 page shown in the image below. If I then tap refine button and then tap back to take me back to _collectonView2 page it displays _collectionView page instead.

_collectionView was created in interface builder and I'm guessing it's recreated every time viewWillAppear runs and just replaces _collectionView2. I've tried to hide it in viewWillAppear e.g. `[_collectionView setHidden:YES];` and this hides it and reveals _collectionView2.

**Single file display:**

[image]

**Here is the code for the UISegmentedControl:**

```
- (void)displayTypeSegmentSelected
{
    _selectedDisplayTypeIndex = [_displayTypeControl selectedSegmentIndex];


    if (_selectedDisplayTypeIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Single file item view selected");
        _fromCollectionView = _collectionView;
        _toCollectionView = _collectionView2;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Grid style view selected");
        _fromCollectionView = _collectionView2;
        _toCollectionView = _collectionView;
    }

    [_fromCollectionView removeFromSuperview];

    [_toCollectionView setFrame:[_superView bounds]];
    [_superView addSubview:_toCollectionView];
    [self createFilterBar];

}
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to let the UINavigation instance know that is was navigated to from the single file display view so that when I click back it doesn't reload _collectionView? but takes make back to _collectionView?

**UPDATE - viewWillAppear code as requested:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"view will appear");



    // Create flow layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    // Set up margins, sizes etc
    [layout setHeaderReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(50,93)];
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500)];
    [layout setMinimumLineSpacing:0];
    [layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0];
    [layout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 40, 0)];
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    // Initialise collection view 2 with frame, attach layout
    _collectionView2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[[_thisController view] frame] collectionViewLayout:layout];

    // Set background colour, delegate and dataSource
    [_collectionView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_collectionView2 setDelegate:_thisController];
    [_collectionView2 setDataSource:_thisController];

    // Grab nib header nib file and give it a reuse identifier
    [_collectionView2 registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VAGHeaderLabelReusableView" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView2"];

    // Grab cell nib file and give a reuse identifier
    [_collectionView2 registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VAGGarmentCell2" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell2"];

    // Add as subview of this controller
    [_collectionView2 setFrame:[[_thisController view] bounds]];
   // [[_thisController view] addSubview:_collectionView2];



    [_thisController setTitle:@"S  H  O  P"];

    // Set to yes so back button isn't hidden and disabled. Note that back title is set to blank on controller that pushes to this one
    [[_thisController navigationItem] setLeftItemsSupplementBackButton: YES];

    // Create nav bar buttons
    UIBarButtonItem *searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"magnify_glass.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:_thisController action:@selector(searchButtonTapped)];
    [[_thisController navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:searchButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *shoppingCartButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping_cart.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:_thisController action:@selector(shoppingCartButtonTapped)];

    UIBarButtonItem *addFavouriteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_fav_heart.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:_thisController action:@selector(addFavouriteButtonTapped)];

    [[_thisController navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:@[shoppingCartButton, addFavouriteButton] animated: YES];

    // Reset refine button colour back to clear after returning from refineButtonTableViewController
    [_refineButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [_navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

    // Create filter bar
    [self createFilterBar];
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that -- when you go back to a view controller, it's subviews should be the same ones that were there when you left it. _collectionView shouldn't be recreated every time viewDidAppear executes, unless that's what you've told it to do. Are you going back using the "back" button? You should show the code you have in viewDidAppear for the controller with the 2 collection views.

Comment: Yep, going back using the "back" button. I've added the code for viewWillAppear. The thing is I don't do anything _collectionView related in my viewWillAppear. That collection view was created in interface builder. I have a shop button that I've connected to _collectionView in interface builder. By default _collectionView is what shows up when that button is tapped. I don't know if what's going on is something to do with the way I'm adding and removing the collection views. It's like the navigation doesn't know that _collectionView2 is on screen and just loads _collectionView after I tap back.

Comment: The navigation controller isn't doing anything with regard to loading views, it's loading the view controller. I don't see anything in the code you've posted so far that would cause your problem. If you could upload you project somewhere, or send it to me directly, I'd be happy to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by presenting the view modally and dismissing it with a cancel button. Subclassed the new controller and in that file created an action connected to my cancel button with code to dismiss the controller when cancel button tapped.

```
#import "VAGRefineResultsTableViewController.h"

@interface VAGRefineResultsTableViewController ()


@end

@implementation VAGRefineResultsTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do stuff here
}

- (IBAction)cancelButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar situation in a project and we decided on simply changing the cell of one collection view and reloading the collection view rather than using two separate collection views. I think this would solve your problem and give you less of a headache to implement since you continue to only manage one collection view. You just check to see the currently visualization selection in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. Conceptually you implement it as:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.currentSelection == kSingleView) {
        return [self cellForSingleView];
    } else {
        return [self cellForGridView];
    }
}
```

If you have multiple visualization styles, you obviously need to check for more values. Then in your viewWillAppear, you simply reload the collection view. Alternatively you may want to only load the collection view in viewDidLoad since that will not be called when the view controller is "popped" to. It also many be a good time to use an enum to define your styles since enums are more scalable than constants.

**EDIT**

For this to work, you must also check for your current selection and set the desired size of the cells in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.currentSelection == kSingleView) {
        // return size of Single View Cell
    } else {
        // return size of Grid View Cell
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you are using different cell identifiers for each cell.

Comment: So basically detect when a segment is tapped and then return appropriate cell for that segment e.g. grid or single file?

Comment: Detect when the segment is tapped, set the selection via the segment's index to an ivar that maintains the current selection (e.g. `kSingleView`), reload your collection view, then in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method check for the current visualization selection and return the appropriate cell.

Comment: I ended up solving this by presenting the view modally.